# How to separate data from view in async function

Tags: javascript, dom, async-await, es6-modules

I'm currently working on a weather application and have trouble separating my data from the view. I currently have this function in this module.

> weather.js

```js
async function getApi() {
try {
    let URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?&units=imperial&appid=02dbfb3b0a9eca931937cb67ff5eba51&q="

    const input = document.getElementById("search").value.trim()
    URL = URL.concat(input)

    const response = await fetch(URL, { mode: "cors" })
    const getData = await response.json()
    // console.log(getData)

    const mainStr = [getData.sys.country, getData.name, getData.main, getData.weather[0].description]

    let serializedObj = JSON.stringify(mainStr, null, " ")
    serializedObj = serializedObj.replace(/["']/g, "").replace(/[{}]/g, "").replace(/[[\]]/g, "")

    document.body.append(serializedObj)
    return getData
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    alert("Location not found, please try again.")
    return undefined
}
}
```

I would like to extract that data so I can move it into my

> dom.js

module so the data can be displayed and modified using the dom. I am not sure how to get there since my variables are function scoped.

Comment: could you add some clarification about `dom.js` file?

Comment: Sure, in the dom.js file it's currently empty I am fetching the data and would like to display that data. Since my variables are scoped to the function I cant access them outside the function.Trying to keep the view and the model separate. @XMehdi01

Comment: Put a `display` function in *dom.js* that accepts the data as an argument, then **call** the function from `getApi` and pass in all the values it needs. Or, for even better separation, since `getApi` already returns the data, use `display(await getApi())` (or `getApi().then(display)`) and just drop all the stringification and dom stuff from `getApi`.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the help and I think I got it to work. What I did is create a function `display(getData)` and dropped off the stringify data and all that and left the `async function getApi()` with just the await operators and URL. Lastly I did `getApi().then((display))` in a button event listener I had and it seems to be working just the same. @Bergi